# Ajax Dynamic Select Form not submiting value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i have a question about a dynamic Select inside a form that does not submit its value so the code sample is:

```
<table>
<form>
<tr>
<td><select>(options values)</select></td>
<td id='fill'></td>
<td><input class='add' type='submit' value=''></td>
</tr>
</form>'
```

so i have a  that when you select an option it calls an AJAX, that calls a PHP file to populate the

```
<input class='add' type='submit' value=''></td>
```

So it creates a new select with other options... the problem is when i submit it it saves all data except the one i created inside the id=fill...

I have inspected the code all names and id's are correct dont know what could it be...

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you share your Ajax code as well? It's difficult to see what's going on otherwise. How are you calling the Ajax? From the PHP code when the page submits?

Comment: function showInfo(str)
{


if (str=="")
  {
 
  document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","php/items/getRow.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

Comment: Its the basic w3schools ajax call php

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using JQuery for Ajax calls. It is much easier to read and does the routine things for you (like adjusting for browser version). You can learn more about this here: [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Also, I am not entirely sure what the goal is, but it sounds like you might want to look at dynamic binding using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Hope that Helps!